# pgfplots, tikz: addlegendentry

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to have the legend entries not vertically placed, but horizontal (next to each other).

Any input :) ? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}


    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={solid},
        every tick/.append style={semithick,color=black}, 
    }


    \begin{axis}[smooth,
    scale only axis = true, width = 0.9\textwidth, height = 0.35\textwidth,
    ymin =0, ymax =10, xmin =0,  xmax=5, 
    ylabel = {y}, 
    xlabel={x},
    grid style ={dashed},
    grid = both,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize, 
        legend pos =north west},
    ]

\addplot [dotted, domain=0:5] {2*x};
\addlegendentry{Eins}; 

\addplot [dashed, domain=0:5] {1.5*x};
\addlegendentry{Zwei}; 


    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `legend columns=2` in order to have two legend entries horizontally.

I don't think that loading of `etex` is needed nowadays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}


    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={solid},
        every tick/.append style={semithick,color=black}, 
    }


    \begin{axis}[smooth,
    scale only axis = true, width = 0.9\textwidth, height = 0.35\textwidth,
    ymin =0, ymax =10, xmin =0,  xmax=5, 
    ylabel = {y}, 
    xlabel={x},
    grid style ={dashed},
    grid = both,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize, 
        legend pos =north west},
      legend columns=2
    ]

\addplot [dotted, domain=0:5] {2*x};
\addlegendentry{Eins}; 

\addplot [dashed, domain=0:5] {1.5*x};
\addlegendentry{Zwei}; 


    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]